# ASP.net, JavaScript/JQuery - Server Sent Events (SSE) not working with ASHX Handler

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a HTTP handler (ASHX) which I am calling from UI side using JQuery `$.ajax()` function. The following things need to happen in this call:

1. A form data is created in UI to upload a file to Handler.ashx.
2. The AJAX request type used is POST.
3. In the Handler.ashx, to display the execution status on UI, I need to send messages to UI which I am doing using `Response.Write()` function and then I am doing a `Response.Flush()`.
4. In the UI end, I am using XHR's "message" event listener to listen to this data sent from server (Server Sent Events - SSE).

The problem is that this event listener is not working and no data is getting passed to UI as event listener is not getting called at all.

Below is my JQuery code:

```
        importAjaxCall = $.ajax({
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                $('#progressBar').show();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
                        $('#percentageImportComplete').text('' + percentComplete + '%');
                        $('#importStatus').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                    }
                }, false);

                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;                            
                    }
                }, false);

                //This method doesn't get called for the SSE's passed
                xhr.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                   //Some execution to be done here based upon the message being passed
                   //I am just doing an alert call for now

                   alert(event.data);
                }, false);

                return xhr;
            },
            type: 'post',
            url: "Handler.ashx",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //Some code to show success status to user
        });
```

And here is my Handler.ashx code:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

    //SSE Sent to show that the code execution started
    Response.Write("data: Code Execution Started");
    Response.Flush();


    /*********    Code to perform some sanity checks present here   **********/


    //SSE sent on successfull sanity checks performed
    Response.Write("data: Sanity Checks Performed");
    Response.Flush();


    /*********  Code to Copy FILE passed to File Store  ********/


    //SSE sent on successfull completion of execution of file copy
    Response.Write("data: File Successfully Copied to File Store");
    Response.Flush(); 

    Response.End();        
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Set the "Content-Type" header to "text/event-stream"
- Specify that the page should not cache

See some actual code below:

Test.aspx

```
Partial Class test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
            Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream"
            'Response.Write(String.Format(":{0}{1}", Space(2048), vbLf))
            'Response.Write(String.Format("retry: 3000{0}", vbLf))

            Dim i As Integer = CInt(Application("lastid"))

            While True
                i += 1
                Application("lastid") = i
                Response.Write(String.Format("id: {0}{1}", i, vbLf))
                Response.Write(String.Format("data: {0:0000000} - {2:hh-mm-ss.fff} {1}{1}", i, vbLf, Now))
                Response.Flush()
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                If i Mod 1 = 0 Then
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var es = new EventSource("**test.aspx**");

    es.onmessage = function (event) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = event.data;
        div.className = "console-text";
        content.insertBefore(div, content.children[0]);
        if (content.children.length > 100) {
            content.removeChild(content.childNodes[100]);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Charles, This didn't work for me.. :( Could you please share the code that worked for you..??

Comment: @AbhishekSirari i have added my actual test code above.

Comment: @AbhishekSirari I used an aspx page, same should work with your handler